# Javascript angle calculation only sometimes wrong

Tags: javascript, transform, angle

I am creating a line chart using D3 and good old divs rather than svg. Partially as an exercise for myself, but also because it's easily flexible and dynamic without listening for page resizes.

It works very well! Except sometimes. Which as you all know is frustrating, because it should either work or not work.

We have the vertical position of the previous point (if there was one) from the bottom of the chart, the vertical position of the current point from the bottom of the chart, and the horizontal space between them.

All calculations are a percentage of total space.

Aspect ratio is maintained via styles. This is the function used to return the resulting skew style:

```
var angle = Math.tan(heightBetweenPoints/widthBetweenPoints);
return "skewY(" + Math.atan(angle) * (180/Math.PI) * (-1) + "deg)";
```

And my line style is:

```
  position: absolute;
  bottom:-3px;
  right:0;
  width:100%;
  height:2px;
  transform-origin:100% 100%;
```

Most of the lines work... but sometimes they don't.

[image: Line Chart]

It's been a minute since I took trig, but I believe this to be the correct calculation. I'm thinking either I'm mistaken, or there's something I'm missing with JavaScript.

I'm aware of and vaguely understand the rounding issues in JavaScript. I've also tried this with the [math](http://mathjs.org/) library thinking that perhaps it was such an error, however the charts produced by each appear to be identical.

Comment: @Teemu `Math.tan(heightBetweenPoints/widthBetweenPoints);` is finding the tangent, no? Again, been a lot of years since I've applied this math, so I may be forgetting... a lot

Comment: Yes, my bad, I didn't take a look how `angle` really was calculated. Anyway, tan(90°) is not defined (`x` becomes to zero, and you can't divide with zero), use [`atan2()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2) instead of `atan()`.

Comment: Why would you need trig to draw a line chart. Just draw a sequence of straight lines from each point to the next.

Comment: @Teemu actually you were right sorta the first time. The answer is that angle should just be `angle=heightBetweenPoints/widthBetweenPoints`. If you want to post that as an answer since you led me to it I'll accept for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`heightBetweenPoints/widthBetweenPoints` is a tangent already. `atan()` returns an angle from a tangent. To fix the problem, calculate the angle from distances:

```
return "skewY(" + Math.atan(heightBetweenPoints / widthBetweenPoints) * (180 / Math.PI) * (-1) + "deg)";
```

In general, when calculating an angle from coordinates, it's safer to use [`Math.atan2()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2) method. It returns a value also for 90° and 270° angles (i.e. when the divider is zero).